# how to change the auto generate id key in sqlserver

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

how to change id 290 and 291 to 1 and 2 in sql server , table - tbl_price

```
id       description quantity unitprice
290       abc          1        444
291       cde          3        333
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Normally there should be no reason to update primary keys.

Comment: actually i have deleted lot of records. and i just want to show two records as a sample and im using search option . retrieving records using id. select * from tbl_price where id between @@@ to @@@

Comment: @krishnamohan What do you mean by auto generate? is that an identity column?

Comment: @krishnamohan: i've provided the link to another (duplicate) question with the same topic. If your business logic relies on a range of values you should not (ab)use the identity column for this. Instead either add another column(f.e. `Sort` or a datetime column) or do it in the query itself. You can use `WITH CTE AS(SELECT RN=ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ID),* FROM T)SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN BETWEEN @x AND @y`.